# How to deal with rounding errors in Shapely

Tags: python, shapely

I have a case which is based on projecting a point on a line and then separate this line on it. My use case is slightly more complicated, but my problem can be reproduced with the following code:

```
from shapely import *
line1 = LineString([(1,1.2), (2,2), (3, 2.), (4,1.2)])
pt = Point(2.5, 1.2)
pr = line1.interpolate(line1.project(pt))
```

By construction, "pr" should be on line1 and their intersection too:

```
line1.contains(pr)
line1.intersects(LineString([pt, pr]))
```

prints two times "True". But changing the input coordinates slightly brakes the workflow:

```
from shapely import *
line1 = LineString([(1,1.2), (2,2), (3, 2.3), (4,1.2)])
pt = Point(2.5, 1.2)
pr = line1.interpolate(line1.project(pt))
line1.contains(pr)
line1.intersects(LineString([pt, pr]))
```

prints "False".

I understand the floating precision problem behind this, but does that mean that I can *never* test for points being on lines? When I construct a line based on a list of points, can I be *sure* that at least all the "construction" points will be on the line?

Comment: Are you able to choose a more granular unit, lets say, millimeters instead of meters?

Comment: @PauloScardine : thanks. Yes, I can easily give away precision if I gain stability. Multipliying my values by 10 makes the trick. But will it work in **all** cases? Shapely continues to work with floats internally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of **`shapely 2.0`** (see [release notes](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/release/2.x.html#support-for-fixed-precision-model-for-geometries-and-in-overlay-functions)), a precision model is now available: the [**`set_precision`**](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/shapely.set_precision.html#shapely.set_precision) function and the `grid_size` parameter for overlay functions.

Using your previous example and setting the same arbitrary precision to the geometries.

```py
from shapely import set_precision
from shapely.geometry import LineString, Point

precision = 1e-10
line1 = set_precision(LineString([(1, 1.2), (2, 2), (3, 2.3), (4, 1.2)]), precision)
pt = set_precision(Point(2.5, 1.2), precision)
pr = set_precision(line1.interpolate(line1.project(pt)), precision)

print(line1.intersects(LineString([pt, pr])))  # True
```

Note: I would have expected the `set_precision` for the `pr` object to be redundant since all of the involved geometries have been created with an arbitrary precision, but that's not the case...

#### `contains` issue

From my experiments, the `contains` predicates is never true for any precision and any combination of precision. I'm not qualified enough in `GEOS`/`shapely` to give a proper explanation.

Still, intuitively I think it has something to do with the types of geometries involved: using the usual `buffer` technique explained by @MikeT, we actually *change the line/point geometry to a **polygon*** which has consequences on the dimensions of the boundaries and interiors of the involved geometries.

Answer (score 14):

Fundamentally, a [precision model](https://web.archive.org/web/20160319073210/https://www.vividsolutions.com/jts/javadoc/com/vividsolutions/jts/geom/PrecisionModel.html) is needed, and there are various plans to implement this into GEOS at some time (don't hold your breath, as this has been under discussion for several years).

Otherwise, the options are distance-based tests (recommended) or more expensive buffer-based techniques by a small adjustment (see [machine epsilon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon)):

```
from shapely.geometry import LineString, Point

line1 = LineString([(1, 1.2), (2, 2), (3, 2.3), (4, 1.2)])
pt = Point(2.5, 1.2)
pr = line1.interpolate(line1.project(pt))

# Distance based
print(line1.distance(pr) == 0.0)  # True

# Buffer based
EPS = 1.2e-16
print(line1.buffer(EPS).contains(pr))  # True
print(line1.buffer(EPS).intersects(LineString([pt, pr])))  # True
```

You can also chain cheaper and expensive tests using an [`or` operator](https://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations), for example:

```
print(line1.contains(pr) or line1.buffer(EPS).contains(pr))
```

which only runs the second and more expensive test if the first one returns `False`.

Comment: Hi @MikeT, thanks for your answer, that's what I was affraid of. I really wish we had a precision model. Or will the trick of working with integers instead of floats (see Paulo's comment above) ensure stability? My use case is more complicated and based on unions: `shapely.ops.polygonize(LinearRing(line1).union(LineString([pt, pr])))` returns different polygons if the two lines intersect or not... _(I wish I could upvote your answer but I havn't enough reputation for that ;)_

Comment: Can these distance tests be used to see when two linestrings touch - in the sense that the last point of the one is the first one of the other? I have encountered linestrings where the points differ by those characteristic 0.0000000001 (due to float inaccuracies)