# How to find which points intersect with a polygon in geopandas?

Tags: python, geography, geopandas

I've been trying to use the "intersects" feature on a geodataframe, looking to see which points lie inside a polygon.  However, only the first feature in the frame will return as true.  What am I doing wrong?

```
from geopandas.geoseries import *

p1 = Point(.5,.5)
p2 = Point(.5,1)
p3 = Point(1,1)

g1 = GeoSeries([p1,p2,p3])
g2 = GeoSeries([p2,p3])

g = GeoSeries([Polygon([(0,0), (0,2), (2,2), (2,0)])])

g1.intersects(g) # Flags the first point as inside, even though all are.
g2.intersects(g) # The second point gets picked up as inside (but not 3rd)
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://geopandas.org/data_structures.html#geoseries):

> Binary operations can be applied between two GeoSeries, in which case
>   the operation is carried out elementwise. The two series will be
>   aligned by matching indices.

Your examples are not supposed to work. So if you want to test for each point to be in a single polygon you will have to do:

```
poly = GeoSeries(Polygon([(0,0), (0,2), (2,2), (2,0)]))
g1.intersects(poly.ix[0])
```

Outputs:

```
    0    True
    1    True
    2    True
    dtype: bool
```

Or if you want to test for all geometries in a specific GeoSeries:

```
points.intersects(poly.unary_union)
```

Geopandas relies on Shapely for the geometrical work. It is sometimes useful (and easier to read) to use it directly. The following code also works as advertised:

```
from shapely.geometry import *

p1 = Point(.5,.5)
p2 = Point(.5,1)
p3 = Point(1,1)

poly = Polygon([(0,0), (0,2), (2,2), (2,0)])

for p in [p1, p2, p3]:
    print(poly.intersects(p))
```

You might also have a look at
[How to deal with rounding errors in Shapely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28028910/how-to-deal-with-rounding-errors-in-shapely) for issues that may arise with points on boundaries.

Answer (score 13):

Since geopandas underwent many performance-enhancing changes recently, answers here are outdated. Geopandas 0.8 introduced many changes that makes handling large datasets a lot faster.

```py
    import geopandas as gpd
    from shapely.geometry import Polygon, Point
    
    points = gpd.GeoSeries([Point(.5,.5), Point(.5,1), Point(1,1), Point(10,10)])
    polys = gpd.GeoSeries([Polygon([(0,0), (0,2), (2,2), (2,0)])])
    
    point_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometry': points})
    poly_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometry': polys})
    
    gpd.overlay(point_gdf, poly_gdf, how='intersection')
```

Answer (score 3):

One way around this seems to be to either get a particular entry (which doesn't work for my application, but may work for someone else's:

```
from geopandas.geoseries import *

p1 = Point(.5,.5)
p2 = Point(.5,1)
p3 = Point(1,1)

points = GeoSeries([p1,p2,p3])

poly = GeoSeries([Polygon([(0,0), (0,2), (2,2), (2,0)])])

points.intersects(poly.ix[0])
```

Another way (more useful for my application) is to intersect with a unary union of the features for the second layer:

```
points.intersects(poly.unary_union)
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the fastest way to do it is by using `geopandas.sjoin`.

```
import geopandas as gpd

gpd.sjoin(pts, poly, how='left', predicate='intersects')
```

Check example: [link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/287243/intersect-points-and-polygons-in-shapely#)

Answer (score 2):

You can easily check which points lies inside a polygon with this simple function below:

```
import geopandas
from shapely.geometry import *

p1 = Point(.5,.5)
p2 = Point(.5,1)
p3 = Point(1,1)

g = Polygon([(0,0), (0,2), (2,2), (2,0)])

def point_inside_shape(point, shape):
    #point of type Point
    #shape of type Polygon
    pnt = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(geometry=[point], index=['A'])
    return(pnt.within(shape).iloc[0])

for p in [p1, p2, p3]:
    print(point_inside_shape(p, g))
```