# Checking whether point is within polygon returns wrong results in Shapely

Tags: python, polygon, point, shapely

I have a polygon as a string in wkt format:

```
polygon_as_string = 'POLYGON ((1190500.159499999 7144386.067199998, 1190487.2751 7144390.519699998,...,1190500.159499999 7144386.067199998))'
```

which I convert to a Shapely's `Polygon` object:

```
import shapely.wkt
polygon = shapely.wkt.loads(polygon_as_string)
```

Then I check with `within()` or with `contains()` functions whether the point is in my polygon.

```
from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon
point = Point(1190500.159499999, 7144386.067199998)
polygon.contains(point)
point.within(polygon)
```

Both functions return `False` although I take the point which is actually inside of the `polygon`.
What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are using the wrong [predicate](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#binary-predicates) to check if a point is inside *or on the boundary* of a polygon.

From [documentation on `contains`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#object.contains) (which is inverse of [`within`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#object.within)):

> **`object.contains(other)`**
>   Returns `True` if no points of other
>   lie in the exterior of the object and **at least one point of the**
>   ***interior* of other lies in the *interior* of object**.

Instead, as your point lies on the boundary, you should use [`intersects`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#object.intersects):

> **`object.intersects(other)`**
>   Returns `True` if the boundary or interior of the object intersect in any way with those of the other.
>
> In other words, geometric objects intersect if they have **any boundary**
>   **or interior point in common**.

(emphasis mine).

---

Small reproducible example:
[image]

```
>>> from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon
>>> Polygon([(0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1), (0, 1)]).contains(Point(1, 1))
False
>>> Point(1, 1).within(Polygon([(0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1), (0, 1)]))
False
>>> Point(1, 1).intersects(Polygon([(0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1), (0, 1)]))
True
```

---

Note, however, that due to precision errors you indeed can have an unexpected result:
[image]

```
>>> Point(2/3, 2).intersects(Polygon([(0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 3)]))
False
>>> Point(2/3, 2).distance(Polygon([(0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 3)]))
>>> 0.0
```

In cases like this you might consider either checking the distance to the polygon as shown above, or dilating your polygon a bit using [`buffer`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#object.buffer):

```
>>> Point(2/3, 2).intersects(Polygon([(0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 3)]).buffer(1e-9))
True
```

Comment: that is very clear and helpful, i understood completely, thank you million times!

Answer (score 0):

The reason could be that the point you are testing sits exactly on top of one of the vertices and due to rounding errors, the point actually moves a little bit and is not on the edge of the polygon anymore.

To check this hypothesis, try to move the test point a little bit towards the center of the polygon.

Comment: Thank you so much! I took centroid of this polygon and it worked)