# Shapely Polygons that should touch don't

Tags: python, geometry, shapely

Here is some Shapely code that creates three square polygons, `p1`, `p2`, and `p3`. `p2` is positioned immediately to the right of `p1`, and `p3` is positioned immediately underneath.

The problem is that Shapely tells me `p1` and `p2` don't touch, whereas `p1` and `p3` do. I can't see what is going wrong here.

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

DELTA = 0.2

def polygonFromPoint(p):
    return Polygon([(p[0]-DELTA*0.5, p[1]-DELTA*0.5),
                    (p[0]-DELTA*0.5, p[1]+DELTA*0.5),
                    (p[0]+DELTA*0.5, p[1]+DELTA*0.5),
                    (p[0]+DELTA*0.5, p[1]-DELTA*0.5)])

p1 = polygonFromPoint([-118.8,35.0])
p2 = polygonFromPoint([-118.6,35.0])
p3 = polygonFromPoint([-118.8,34.8])

print(p1)
print(p2)
print(p3)

print(p1.overlaps(p2), p1.intersects(p2), p1.crosses(p2), p1.contains(p2),
      p1.disjoint(p2), p1.touches(p2))
print(p1.overlaps(p3), p1.intersects(p3), p1.crosses(p3), p1.contains(p3),
      p1.disjoint(p3), p1.touches(p3))
```

Running this produces the following output:

```
POLYGON ((-118.9 34.9, -118.9 35.1, -118.7 35.1, -118.7 34.9, -118.9 34.9))
POLYGON ((-118.7 34.9, -118.7 35.1, -118.5 35.1, -118.5 34.9, -118.7 34.9))
POLYGON ((-118.9 34.7, -118.9 34.9, -118.7 34.9, -118.7 34.7, -118.9 34.7))
False False False False True False
False True False False False True
```

Which shows that Shapely thinks `p1` and `p2` don't intersect or touch, whereas `p1` and `p3` intersect and touch.

EDIT: As Gilles-Philippe Paillé and others remarked, this is a precision problem with the polygon coordinates. Using the following tweak fixes the issue in this case:

```
def polygonFromPoint(p):
    return Polygon( [(round(p[0]-DELTA*0.5,1), round(p[1]-DELTA*0.5,1)),
                        (round(p[0]-DELTA*0.5,1), round(p[1]+DELTA*0.5,1)),
                        (round(p[0]+DELTA*0.5,1), round(p[1]+DELTA*0.5,1)),
                        (round(p[0]+DELTA*0.5,1), round(p[1]-DELTA*0.5,1))] )
```

Comment: Computers can only represent an approximation of most floating point numbers, so you cannot expect comparisons of values calculated from them to be exact. You may be able to work around this limitation by using only integer coordinates.

Comment: See related [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: Thanks - your point is well taken! However, I am not making any comparisons in my code, I am asking the Shapely library to do whatever math is required to determine if the polygons are touching etc., based on the precise coordinates given. Should it not take care of handling the precision of its own calculations? Edit: perhaps I'm not giving it as precise coordinates as I think, as Paille shows below.

Comment: Yes, I understand that…and it sounds to me like it's due to a bug in Shapely's implementation of `touches()` — it's a Comp Sci 101 kind of mistake (and your mention of "precise coordinates" makes me suspect you may still not get that there's no such thing on a computer, either).

Comment: No, you are correct. See my revised question, where I round to one decimal place and it works. It's curious that Shapely, when printing the polygon, doesn't show the full precision of the numbers it is using, otherwise it would have been immediately obvious that there was a precision issue :-)

Comment: Even if it was the "full precision" of the number, there's a related problem that it's often not possible to correctly print the decimal representation of the binary floating point number stored internally — so whatever you see printed is also an approximation (of something that may itself be an approximation of something else `;¬)`.

Comment: I'd like to add one more thing after seeing your edit — a better way would be to see if the difference between the two values was something less than a relatively small value, like say `0.00001`. Using `round()` makes me a little nervous because it may involve doing more floating-point math.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to deal with rounding errors in Shapely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28028910/how-to-deal-with-rounding-errors-in-shapely)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if the string representation of the polygon show that the coordinates are the same, the underlying floating point representation is not exactly what is printed and may include some imprecision. Using your coordinates and the same calculation, I get:

```
DELTA = 0.5

a = -118.6 - 0.2 * DELTA
b = -118.8 + 0.2 * DELTA
print(a)
print(b)
print(a <= b)

a = 35.0 - 0.2 * DELTA
b = 34.8 + 0.2 * DELTA
print(a)
print(b)
print(a <= b)
```

which gives the following output:

```
-118.69999999999999
-118.7
False
34.9
34.9
True
```